# ServiceStack How can I autowire my custom IRepository<T> property on MyController<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, servicestack

Asp.Net mvc with ServiceSTack Mvc powerpack

There is a row in AppHost:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
```

So this is my code

```
public class BaseController<T>:Controller
{
   protected IRepository<T> Repository {get;set;}

   public ActionResult Detail(T t){}
}

public class CarController:BaseController<Car>
{
}
```

I will use this code in App.Host

```
container.Register<IRepository<Car>>(c => new CarRepository());
```

How can I AutoWire Repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only public properties or constructors get injected, so try make Repository public with:

```
public class BaseController<T>:Controller
{
   public IRepository<T> Repository {get;set;}

   public ActionResult Detail(T t){}
}

public class CarController:BaseController<Car> {}
```

Also if you are using the [MVC PowerPack](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/) you may want to inherit from the [ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs#L51) instead which gives you a lot of benefits, like using ServiceStack's JSON serialization, have access to ServiceStack's shared [Cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) and Session providers as well as be able to share ServiceStack [Authentication/Authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) features on both MVC Controllers and [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) web services (if you're using any).

Comment: How can I autowire another properties for example: There is XRepository in XProvider class? Ps: I've asked here because this question is closely related with main question.

Comment: The largest constructor and all public properties get injected with an instance of the same type you've registered in your IOC. For more info read: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container

Comment: Neihter container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<XRepository, IRepository<X>>(); nor    container.Register<IRepository<X>>(c => new XRepository());
            container.RegisterAutoWired<IRepository<X>>(); works?

Comment: Then you will need to submit a failing unit test since everything works as expected on our side, i.e. Whatever type you registered gets injected into dependencies exposed via public properties.

Comment: You can add tests above to IoCTests.cs in ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests. I've used same classes

Comment: 1) Don't add example code in comments - link to a gist instead. 2) There's so much wrong with these examples that they show a lack of understanding of how IOC's work and how to use them properly. Most of the assumptions in the test don't make any sense. I've rewritten the example so it passes and show what proper usage looks like: https://gist.github.com/2822977 - My advice is to read-up on and get familiar with using IOCs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11856/discussion-between-oguz-karadenizli-and-mythz)